# Of what functionality are the middleman files created by protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

After Downloading protobuf-2.5.0 and playing around with the addressbook example given I noticed there are two files, `javac_middleman` and `protoc_middleman` which upon initial inspection  (`$ file *middleman`)  are just empty files.  They are also created/referenced in the makefile included with the example, but what is their actual purpose/functionality?

The makefile can be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/examples/Makefile?r=177